# Meteor - Remove Event Map Listeners

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Meteor makes it easy to add event listeners natively, but how would one go about removing an event listener natively?

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click #dashboard-ul li': function(e) {

  }
});
```

I want to remove the click event on '#dashboard-ul li' in the above through Blaze or Meteor's native remove event listener methods.

I could not find any mention of event removal in the meteor docs besides removing the element outright.

Comment: There's no official way to remove an event listener. However, if you need to do that, you probably have a poor design. Can you show us your use-case?

Comment: I don't think using a native remove event listener method for Meteor is a bad design. Lets say that I am working with a multiple choice quiz game where I have choices for each question and each choice has an click event listener. After a question is answered the choices will be shown on the screen, but the screen scrolls up with a new question but leaves the old questions on the screen with its choices. I need to remove the event listeners from the answered questions because they do not need them any more.

Comment: In your case, I would show unanswered questions in one way, and answered in another (this also makes the user understand that he can't change a choice he has already made). For example, unanswered question choices can be shown as `<input type="radio">`, while answered can be shown as ` <input type="radio" disabled="true">`. `disabled` elements won't fire any events, but you could of course use other tags instead.